# Adding a background image to a root window and placing labels on the top of the background image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to add a background image to my root window but it doesn't seem to be working for me. This is my code. I would like the background image to cover the whole window and place the labels on top of the background image.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


top = Tk()
textButton = Frame(top)
textButton.pack()

img = PhotoImage(file="bk.gif")
img = img.subsample(1, 1)
background = Label(top, image = img, bd=0)
background.pack()
background.image = img

name_label = Label(textButton, text="Username")
name_label.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

name_entry = Entry(textButton)## the Entry will let the user entre text inside the text box
name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)


password_label = Label(textButton, text="Password")
password_label.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

password_entry = Entry(textButton, show="*")
password_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)


top.mainloop
```

Comment: you have to use `background` as parent for `Frame`  to put frame inside `Label` with image. But you have to know that all widgets has gray background which you can't remove. You may have to use `Canvas` to put text without background.

Comment: you forgot `()` in `top.mainloop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `background` as parent for widgets to put them inside `Label` with background.

I remove `Frame` to make it simpler. And now I can use `weight` to automatically resize empty rows and columns around widgets so they will be in the center.

```
import tkinter as tk

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry('250x250')

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="hal_9000.gif")
img = img.subsample(1, 1)

background = tk.Label(top, image=img, bd=0)
background.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
background.image = img

# resize empty rows, columns to put other elements in center
background.rowconfigure(0, weight=100)
background.rowconfigure(3, weight=100)
background.columnconfigure(0, weight=100)
background.columnconfigure(3, weight=100)

name_label = tk.Label(background, text="Username")
name_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='news')

name_entry = tk.Entry(background)## the Entry will let the user entre text inside the text box
name_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

password_label = tk.Label(background, text="Password")
password_label.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='news')

password_entry = tk.Entry(background, show="*")
password_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)

top.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

As you see widgets have gray background which you can't remove. If you need text without gray background then you have to use [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) with [create_text()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method) (and [create_window()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method) to put `Entry`)

---

Gif file (with [HAL 9000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_9000)) to test code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I have been trying to do more than two days. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `place` to use an image as a background for other widgets. `place` doesn't affect the geometry of other widgets so you can use it with `grid` or `pack`.

The main think to keep in mind is that you should do this before creating other widgets so that it is lowest in the stacking order. That, or be sure to call `lower` on it, otherwise it will overlay the other widgets rather than underlay them.

With your code, just remove `background.pack()` and replace it with these two lines:

```
background.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
background.lower()
```

You don't need to change anything else. The above centers the image. If you instead want the image to start in the upper-left corner you can do it like this:

```
background.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw")
```