# Expanding the background image to fit window and stacking the frames over it in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add a background image to my GUI app using tkinter. In the root window, I have two frames, named container_1 and container_2. When I am adding the background image, these framed are pushed outside the image. I can see them as the window size is higher than image size. If it is less, it isn't even visible. How can I make them place over the background image? Is it possible to give different background images for container_1 and container_2?
ans suggestions please.

(imgae in the comment link)

```
import tkinter as tk

def FnToShow():
    container_2.pack(side="right",expand=True, fill="x", padx=1, pady=1)

def FnToHide():
    container_2.pack_forget()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
#bg image
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(file= "bgPic.png")
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.pack() # is pack problematic here?

container_1 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
container_2 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")

settingBtn  = tk.Button(container_1, text="Settings", command= FnToShow)
settingBtn.grid(row=6, column=4)

setting_1 = tk.Label(container_2, text="Setting-1", fg='#000000')
setting_1.grid(row=3, column=10)
setting_2 = tk.Label(container_2, text="Setting-2", fg='#000000')
setting_2.grid(row=4, column=10)
closeSettingBtn  = tk.Button(container_2, text="close Settings", command= FnToHide)
closeSettingBtn.grid(row=5, column=10)

container_1.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="x", padx=1, pady=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the image i used for experiment is here.  [link](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enDE838DE839&biw=1920&bih=920&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=gmk5XYyTFYuvUL-lg3A&q=blue+shades+for+background&oq=blue+shades+for+background&gs_l=img.3...2536.8832..9180...0.0..0.114.2445.19j7......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67j0j0i8i30.mkEId5Y29hQ&ved=0ahUKEwiM3MTR1M_jAhWLFxQKHb_SAA4Q4dUDCAY&uact=5#imgrc=o7N7UspQM0sg-M:)

Comment: The answers to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983005/adding-a-background-image-to-a-root-window-and-placing-labels-on-the-top-of-the might help you.

Comment: I tried. but frames `container_1` and `container_2` are problematic !

Comment: it was simple.! `background_label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")`

Answer (score 1):

```
#setting background image
background_main_img=tk.PhotoImage(file= "bgMain.png")
background_main = tk.Label(root, image=background_main_img)
background_main.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

#setting background image for container frame
background_con_1=tk.PhotoImage(file= "bgContainer.png")
background_label = tk.Label(container_1, image=background_con_1)
background_label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
```